# How can i set the delimiter as an argument in the match() function?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, sh

```
awk '{while(match($0,/("[^"]+",|[^,]*,|([^,]+$))/,a)){
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);b[++x]=a[0]}
     print b[1] b[4];x=0}' file
```

I want to understand the match clause and want to know how can I make it dynamic so that it can take the delimiter as an argument instead of hard-coding it to comma.

I tried this, but it didnt work as i dont have the background for this function.

```
awk -v dl '{while(match($0,/("[^"]+"dl|[^,]*dl|([^,]+$))/,a)){
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);b[++x]=a[0]}
     print b[1] b[4];x=0}' file
```

Input File data:

```
a,b,c,"d,e,f",  
"a,b",c,d,"e,f",  
p,q,r,"s,u",
```

Desired output (may be 4th field):

```
d,e,f  
e,f  
s,u
```

Desired output (may be 5th field, so it should generate the 3 rows with blank value):

Here , Delimiter can be anything comma, pipe and desired field number is also dynmaic.. thats why i wanted to pass the argument for field number and delimiter..
Field number argument is working fine but not the delimiter argument?

As suggested by Anubhava, i used that fpat which works really fine but it is not giving any rows when fetching the column 5th form the input file?

Comment: wrt `it is not giving any rows when fetching the column 5th form the input file` - you don't have any 5th column data in your input file, you always have 4 fields then a final `,` then nothing so your 5th column is always just null.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the reply...actually I have provided the sample record to Anubhava and in the sample data(provided in question) there are 4 delimiter in each row, which means it should have the 5th column.... but to make it more visible i should have added the header..

Comment: It does have a 5th column, there just isn't any data in it. - that's my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk`, you can define a `FPAT` variable that is a regular expression for matching fields.

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '{gsub(/"/, "", $4); print $4}' file
```

```
d,e,f
e,f
s,u
```

---

Running it from a shell script that takes delimiter as argument:

```
dl="${1?}"
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^'"$dl"']*' '{gsub(/"/, "", $4); print $4}' "${2?}"
```

Then run it as:

```
bash p.sh ',' 'file'
```

Comment: i tried this and the above one.. but unfortunately both are returning blank for me.. not sure what is the issue... i just put this in a shell script and instead of file i put $1 and then passing the file name..

Comment: its 4... sorry my bad.. actually as suggested in above solution i used the variable dl into your script.. there it is creating problem.. if i am using your solution as it is then its working good but as asked in the main question, i want to pass the delimiter also as a variable.. can you please suggest how that can be achieved via this solution

Comment: yes sure... so my input file is same as above with a change where i replaced the comma with pipe.. named it as p.csv   ...... my script is p.sh as   --------- awk -v dl=$2 FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^"dl"]*' '{gsub(/"/, "", $4); print $4}' $1 ......... and i am calling it as ..... sh p.sh p.csv "|"      and i want to pass the field number as argument also, so can we please set argument instead of $4?

Comment: dl="${1?}"  fl="${3?}"
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^'"$dl"']*' '{gsub(/"/, "", $'"$fl"'); print $'"$fl"'}' "${2?}"   Yes this one is working good.. can you please check and confirm if i am doing any mistake here.. and can you please tell me why we need to define  the argument like this while in normal script we just do this dl=$2

Comment: `dl="${1?}"` sets `dl` as value of `$1` but it will return an error if `$1` is not passed to shell script.

Comment: it's failing for one scenario. Suppose i have a column 5 and all 4 data rows dont have any data for column 5 then its not returning 5 rows with blank value

Comment: If your data is always in last column then use `$NF` instead of `$4`

Comment: its a data file so data can be or can not be in last column. it depend on source. So how should we handle this

Comment: It has to come from your requirement. Given a row of unknown number of columns what column do you want to extract?

Comment: oh sorry, i think i misunderstood your question.. so row is having fixed number of columns for a particular source file. but its a generic script which will work on all the source system .. i am calculating the number of columns in the very initial steps , so can we use that as gsub(/"/, "", $col_count) .. or it should be done by some other approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220363/discussion-between-anubhava-and-sandeep-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

That regex was strange, so I'll rewritten it. The regex:

```
/("[^"]+",|[^,]*,|([^,]+$))/
```

the `"[^"]+"` is parsed like - first `"` and last `"` are quotation marks and `[^"]+` matches everything except quotes. So it's the same as:

```
"([^\"]+,|[^,]*,|([^,]+$))"
```

I guess that you want to match a field `[^,]+` or a quoted field `\"[^\"]+\"` followed by a delimiter or end of line `(,|$)`. So match that. And in matching groups match the insides of the fields, so match `\"([^\"]+)\"` or the unquoted field `([^,]+)` and then use those matching groups

```
awk -v dl=, '{
    x = 0;
    while (match($0, "^(\"([^\"]+)\"|([^" dl "]+))(" dl "|$)", a)) {
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH);
        b[++x] = a[2] a[3];   # funny, one of them will be empty
    }
    print b[4];
}' <<EOF
a,b,c,"d,e,f"
"a,b",c,d,"e,f"
p,q,r,"s,u"
EOF

d,e,f
e,f
s,u
```

Comment: thank you for sharing the knowledge on match. it is helpful..though when i tried it with Pipe delimeter, it didnt work.. ---awk -v dl="|" '{
    x = 0;
    while (match($0, "^(\"([^\"]+)\"|([^" dl "]+))(" dl "|$)", a)) {
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH);
        b[++x] = a[2] a[3];   # funny, one of them will be empty
    }
    print b[4];
}'     It was returning blank rows... I am checking at my end but your help will be really required.